# Start and stop logger in python 3.2

Tags: python, logging, python-3.x

In my application, I use two buttons: One for START recording of RS422 link messages and one for STOP the record.

The first time, the application runs correctly : Creation of a .txt file with the messages.
The second time, when I click on the START button, a new . txt file is created but, now, messages are recording in this file but also in the first .txt file.

See my code :

```
def start_clic(self):
    logger=logging.getlogger("CFD")
    stringfilename=datetime.now().strftime('log_%Y_%m_%H_%M.txt')
    filehandler=logging.FileHandler(stringfilename)
    formatter=logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s')
    logger.addHandler(filehandler)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def stop_clic(self):
    logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    filehandler.close()
```

Does somebody have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to remove the handlers if you want to stop logging like that, using the [`Logger.removeHandler()` method](http://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.removeHandler):

```
def stop_clic(self):
    logger=logging.getlogger("CFD")
    logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    logger.removeHandler(filehandler)
    filehandler.close()
```

otherwise it'll continue to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure in 3.2, but in 3.6 you can do: `logger.disabled = True`