# How close and remove logfile in module logging?

Tags: python, logging

```
import logging, os


appPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


def main(): 
    pass

errorLogPath = appPath + '//myappErrorLog.log'

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG, 
    filename = errorLogPath,
    filemode='w+',
    format= '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
)

try:
    main()
    os.remove(errorLogPath) #error
except:
    logging.exception("myapp:")
```

file not removed on windows platform (unix normal), error - WindowsError: [Error 32] Process can not access the file.

how right to close and remove file using the module logging?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the log file? Note that, until the module completes, it's *still being logged*.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14523996/3001761

Comment: I'm going to run this script in cron, it can work for a long time,  if logfile exists new copy will not run, also script finished with error

Comment: Are you saying that one cron job might not end before the next cron job begins?

Comment: Yes absolutely right

Comment: I tried logging.shutdown() before os.remove , it work, how is that correct ?

Comment: But then the first cron job might not finish `main()` before the second job starts. If so, then the call to `os.remove` will not execute anyway. It seems a proper solution therefore requires adapting the script to allow the file to be opened twice, or to time stamp the log files.... or maybe just run the cron job once and keep one script running...

Comment: you're right , it is not the entire script , I will check if a file exists if there is the main () else os.abort ()